# openlayers 3 - fullscreen

Tags: openlayers

Openlayers 3 knows the ol.control.FullScreen() control. When pressed you will get a fullscreen map.

What I would like to know is: to what event should i listen te detect the fullscreen control is pressed?

In this event I would like to do a zoom-to-extent like this:

```
var extent = source.getExtent();
map.getView().fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());
```

Comment: Updated - http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/162152/50718

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Jonatas Walker's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/162152/115) to [OpenLayers Add EventListener for Fullscreen close](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162136/openlayers-add-eventlistener-for-fullscreen-close) ...

You could add an EventListener as

```
fullscreen.on('change', function(evt){
    console.log(evt);
});
```

Which should be fired once either the fullscreen is entered or left, and with some logic you could determine if it is enter and do your zoom-to-extent.