# OpenLayers Add EventListener for Fullscreen close

Tags: openlayers, events, angularjs

I'm currently building a web-app with Angular and OpenLayers. Due to the nature of my site I need to call map.updateSize() when the screen changes size which works as expected.

However when I enter fullscreen using OpenLayers own FullScreen control my maps streches fine but when closing fullscreen it keeps the fullscreen aspect and needs to be updated, hence a call to map.updateSize().

From [OL3 ol.control.FullScreen](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.control.FullScreen.html) there is an eventlistener on, however I don't know what to bind it to and how to write it. Can anyone provide me with an example, hopefully with the event of closing the fullscreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
Digging a bit, here's what I've found. If you want to listen on fullscreen you may register the listener on [`document`](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/d3c8880b22c61b617989f4e3b5d9eaba1364385c/src/ol/control/fullscreencontrol.js#L70). Now, the event has different name for each browser so to webkit family:

```
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function(evt) {
    console.log('fullscreen...');
    console.log(evt);

});
```

And the others: `mozfullscreenchange`, `MSFullscreenChange` and `fullscreenchange`. Taken from ol-debug.js:

```
goog.dom.fullscreen.EventType = {
  /** Dispatched by the Document when the fullscreen status changes. */
  CHANGE: (function() {
    if (goog.userAgent.WEBKIT) {
      return 'webkitfullscreenchange';
    }
    if (goog.userAgent.GECKO) {
      return 'mozfullscreenchange';
    }
    if (goog.userAgent.IE) {
      return 'MSFullscreenChange';
    }
    // Opera 12-14, and W3C standard (Draft):
    // https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html
    return 'fullscreenchange';
  })()
};
```

A listener would be written like:

```
var fullscreen = new ol.control.FullScreen();
map.addControl(fullscreen);

fullscreen.on('propertychange', function(evt){
    console.log(evt);
});

fullscreen.on('change', function(evt){
    console.log(evt);
});
```

But neither fires anything. Have you noticed that Openlayers already do this for you? https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.8.2/src/ol/control/fullscreencontrol.js#L149

Are you using latest version?

Comment: No I haven't noticed that OpenLayers already do this, and it isn't working quite as expected. I'm trying to build up a simple example to seperate the complex app with this specific issue as it must be a bug in the web-app when OL already handles it. And I'm using version 3.8.2.

Comment: Maybe you could make a simplified fiddle demo. It could be something related to angularjs.

Comment: As said, I'm brewing on it at the moment, but apparently eventlisteners and fullscreen doesn't work properly in jsfiddle. Hopefully I'll have it ready sometime tomorrow.

Comment: I've also been digging and found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu41rhho/3/) which shows some strange behavior of OpenLayers even without fullscreen, so my guess it have some flaws when dynamically change the size of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on OL 6 and had the same issue. I managed to solve it by looking for the button class that is applied to the fullscreen button relative to its active state. It is `ol-full-screen-false` and `ol-full-screen-true` respectivly.

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function(e) {
  let is_fullscreen = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-full-screen-false')

  if(is_fullscreen.length) { // We're in Fullscreen mode
    // do something
  } 
});
```